# How to detect URL redirections and separate each header?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, http-status-codes

I have a problem: i want to detect all redirections of a 3xx response code and separate each header of URL. I investigated that get_headers function follows redirections and put it in an array of each component of redirection. I know that "fb.com" **redirects 3 times** as you can see on this page:

[image]

I want to do the same thing of that page, and am trying to do so:

[image]

But my PHP code seems to be wrong. Here it is:

```
<?php
$header = array();
$header[] = array();
$header_url = @get_headers('http://fb.com',1);

/*
foreach ($header_url as $key => $value){
    echo $key . " = " . $value . "<br />";
}
*/

$a = 0;
foreach($header_url as $key => $value){
    if(is_int($key)){
        $header[$a][] = $value;
        $a++;
    } else if(!is_int($key) && !is_object($key)){
       $header[0][$key] = $value;
    } else if(!is_int($key) && is_object($key)){
        foreach ($key as $key2 => $value2){
            $header[$key2][$key] = $value2;
        }
    }
}
echo "<h1>ONE</h1>";
foreach ($header[0] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " = " . $value . "<br />";
}
echo "<h1>TWO</h1>";
foreach ($header[1] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " = " . $value . "<br />";
}
echo "<h1>THREE</h1>";
foreach ($header[2] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " = " . $value . "<br />";
}
?>
```

I would appreciate help on what i am doing wrong.
THANKS SO MUCH AND HAVE A NICE DAY DEV!

Comment: `get_headers` follows all the redirections and just shows the final headers. You need to use `cURL` to have fine-grained control.